# Angular not showing html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm implementing Angular for the first time. I'm using factories, controllers and templates (don't know if there's another way) in Eclipse. So, I'm redirecting to my index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="list" data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="../css/stylesheet1.css"   />
<title>App</title>
 <!-- Include the AngularJS library -->
    <script src="../js/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<!-- Modules -->
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/factories/objectFactory.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/factories/usersFactory.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/controllers/headerCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/controllers/listCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/controllers/objectHandlerCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="headerCtrl as headerVM"> 
        <nav id="links">
            <div class="inner"><button onclick="location.href ='#!/createObject'">Create</button></div>
            <div class="inner"><button onclick="location.href ='#!/editUser'">Edit user</button></div>
            <div class="inner"><button onclick="location.href ='#!/deleteUser'">Delete user</button></div>
            <div class="inner"><button onclick="location.href ='../LogOutServlet'">Exit</button></div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the third line starting at the end I have a div that should be dinamically changed with angular depending on the upper buttons, but, although the url change when I press the buttons, this area is empty.

To coordinate the route, I have the app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            controller: "listCtrl",
            controllerAs: "listVM",
            templateUrl: "listObjectTemplate.html",
            resolve: {
                delay: function($q, $timeout) {
                var delay = $q.defer();
                $timeout(delay.resolve, 500);
                return delay.promise;
                }
            }
        })
        .when("/createObject", {
            controller: "objectHandlerCtrl",
            controllerAs: "objectHandlerVM",
            templateUrl: "noteHandlerTemplate.html"
    })
    .when("/editObject/:ID", {
            controller: "objectHandlerCtrl",
            controllerAs: "objectHandlerVM",
            templateUrl: "objectHandlerTemplate.html"
    })
    .when("/deleteNote/:ID", {
            controller: "objectHandlerCtrl",
            controllerAs: "objectHandlerVM",
            templateUrl: "objectHandlerTemplate.html"
    });
})
```

I will not add more code unless you think it's necessary to keep this simple.

So, is it necessary some other configuration? Right now the angular part is not working at all (the div seems to be empty no matter the changes in the url).

I'm using AngularJS 1.6.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing ng-controller  **`data-ng-controller="headerCtrl as headerVM"`** which is not necessary since you are configuring on the route config

Comment: ...and that was it. I've been working on this a couple of days now, many thanks.

Comment: you are wecome , glad it helped